# Passing data between views in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I currently am writing a web app that needs to pass some configuration settings from a settings page to a page page with a search box.

Currently I'm passing the config data from the settings page to the home page with:

```
public ActionResult Settings(Configuration configuration)
{
    return RedirectToAction("ConfigSet", "Home", configuration);
}
```

And in the home controller:

```
public ActionResult ConfigSet(Configuration configuration)
{            
    return View("Index");
}
```

I'm generating a partial view with:

```
    public PartialViewResult Search(string q)
    {
        List<Stuff> results = this.Search(q);
        return PartialView("SearchResults", results);
    }
```

With the partial view rendered like so:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Home", new AjaxOptions {
HttpMethod = "GET",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
UpdateTargetId = "searchResults",
}))
{
    <input type="text" name="searchString" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

My question is how would i pass the configuration settings to the partial view? I've been thinking about this for a couple of days and am really confused about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a viewModel which will store your configuration setting like this

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public Configuration configuration {get;set;}
   public List<Stuff> results {get;set;} 
}
```

& in your action return MyViewModel

```
public PartialViewResult Search(Configuration config)     
{
  var model = new  MyViewModel();
  //set its properties       
  model.results = this.Search(q);    
  model.configuration = configurationObject;     
  return PartialView("SearchResults", model);     
}
```

if you again want to pass configuration to controller then

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Home", new { config = Model.configuration } new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "searchResults", })) 
{     
     <input type="text" name="searchString" />     
     <input type="submit" value="Search" /> 
}
```

Comment: thanks. However, I'm not sure how I pass the config which is set on the settings page to the search viewresult method. I can pass the data to the master page via the configset method, but can't get the config to the search method using your idea.

Comment: In your ajax.beginform, you can render all your configuration stuff from model.configuration; On ajax request submit which is going to call search action, for that you will have to change the signature to `public PartialViewResult Search(configuration config)`

Comment: Updated the answer, have a look

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I don't think that'll work sorry: the first time the user goes to the homepage (where the search method is called) the new { config = Model.configuration } isn't set.

Comment: when user goes to homepage for the first time, you set config into viewmodel & pass it to view ; You will have to set it up in controller only

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to get your configuration settings in the Search action method on the server? To do it cleanly, you either have to roundtrip them to the client and back, which seems illogical and possibly insecure (depending what is in your config), or you need to retrieve them again within the Search action itself.

Comment: The config settings are set in a view by the user. Then they will return to the home page (I have separate controllers for both views). How do I send the config settings to the search class, given that the this.search method is called from the HomeController?

Comment: Don't you persist the user settings to a database? If not, you are really talking about having session settings only, in which case you need to use the server's Session object itself, or store them in a cookie, or on the ViewModel for each view, have a common property called UserSettings which is a string that you serialize and deserialize each request. If you do the latter, have a BaseViewModel that does the work for you.